# MongoDB attribute

Tags: c#, mongodb, attributes

I'm using MongoDB for an application. I have a Collection in my db named Role with the following fields: Id, Role and I cannot change these names.
In my VS code, I have a class named Role:

```
  public class Role
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }
    [BsonElement]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I have an errOR that says the element Role doesn't match the fields from db.
I wonder if there exists an attribiute I can use to keep the "Name" property and not change it to "Role" because I cannot have a property named like my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [mongo-csharp-driver reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.5/reference/bson/mapping/#element-name), you specify an element name using attributes.

Have you tried specifying element name like this?

```
public class Role
{
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string ApplicationName { get; set; }

    [BsonElement("Role")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for "Name" Property:

```
[BsonElement("Role")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```